# Interpolating to minute granularity using pandas groupby and interpolate

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, interpolation

I have a dataframe looking like the dataframe dogdata below, and I'd like to groupby location and type and linearly interpolate size by a minute datetime resolution

```
dogdata.set_index('datetime').groupby(['location', 'type'])
```

| size | datetime | location | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.82 | 4/7/2022 9:43:07 AM | doghouse | pitbull |
| 0.73 | 4/7/2022 9:40:58 AM | doghouse | pitbull |
| 0.66 | 4/7/2022 9:36:57 AM | doghouse | pitbull |
| 7.06 | 4/7/2022 5:12:01 AM | doghouse | husky |
| 6.87 | 4/7/2022 5:10:12 AM | doghouse | husky |
| 6.77 | 4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM | doghouse | husky |

Can someone please help me figure out what I need to do to make a dataframe that looks like this? (the 'wanted' size column is not exact, just a showcase of how it would linearly interpolate using the change in size over the change in datetime)

| size | datetime | location | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.819 | 4/7/2022 9:43:00 AM | doghouse | pitbull |
| 0.761 | 4/7/2022 9:42:00 AM | doghouse | pitbull |
| 0.731 | 4/7/2022 9:41:00 AM | doghouse | pitbull |
| 0.729 | 4/7/2022 9:40:00 AM | doghouse | pitbull |
| 0.701 | 4/7/2022 9:39:00 AM | doghouse | pitbull |
| 0.669 | 4/7/2022 9:38:00 AM | doghouse | pitbull |
| 0.662 | 4/7/2022 9:37:00 AM | doghouse | pitbull |
| 0.654 | 4/7/2022 9:36:00 AM | doghouse | pitbull |
| 7.163 | 4/7/2022 5:13:00 AM | doghouse | husky |
| 7.059 | 4/7/2022 5:12:00 AM | doghouse | husky |
| 6.945 | 4/7/2022 5:11:00 AM | doghouse | husky |
| 6.869 | 4/7/2022 5:10:00 AM | doghouse | husky |
| 6.813 | 4/7/2022 5:09:00 AM | doghouse | husky |
| 6.772 | 4/7/2022 5:08:00 AM | doghouse | husky |
| 6.768 | 4/7/2022 5:07:00 AM | doghouse | husky |

Answer (score 0):

First, convert string to datetime using [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and set it as index. Next, resample the data using [`asfreq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) to a 60 sec frequency and fill the missing values using [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html?highlight=ffill#pandas.DataFrame.ffill).

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """size  datetime    location    type
0.82    4/7/2022 9:43:07 AM doghouse    pitbull
0.73    4/7/2022 9:40:58 AM doghouse    pitbull
0.66    4/7/2022 9:36:57 AM doghouse    pitbull
7.06    4/7/2022 5:12:01 AM doghouse    husky
6.87    4/7/2022 5:10:12 AM doghouse    husky
6.77    4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM doghouse    husky"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter='\t')

print(df.dtypes)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df.asfreq('60s')
df.ffill(inplace=True)
```

**Output:**

```
                     size             datetime  location   type
datetime                                                       
2022-04-07 05:07:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:08:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:09:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:10:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:11:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:12:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:13:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:14:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:15:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:16:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:17:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:18:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:19:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:20:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:21:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:22:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:23:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:24:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:25:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:26:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:27:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:28:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:29:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:30:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:31:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
2022-04-07 05:32:35  6.77  4/7/2022 5:07:35 AM  doghouse  husky
```

Comment: I have an issue using datetime as my index, since I have multiple datetimes for different location-type pairs. For each location like doghouse, park, car I have multiple types like husky, pitbull, rottweiler. Do you know what the syntax is for performing this using the groupby function?